# VS Code: debug project .NET Core project that resides in a subfolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

After moving my .NET Core project into a subfolder in the solution I am no longer able to Debug it using VS Code.

If I move `tasks.json` and `launch.json` into the project folder and open VS Code there I am able to debug, but I would like to be able to open the entire solution in VS Code.

The error message I am getting is this:

`MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.`

The error seems to state that my task runner can no longer find my project, so I tried adding this to `tasks.json`:

```
{    
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ],

    // My addition
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/myProjectFolder"
    }
}
```

Doing this I am able to start the task, but I then get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
```

How do I configure the .NET Core debugger to be able to run a project that resides in a sub folder?

Comment: I am having this same problem.  Did you ever find out the solution?

Comment: Nope, I've resolved to opening VS Code from the project folder whenever I need to debug

Answer (score 6):

The problem is your `tasks.json`, you should copy your subfolder `.vscode/tasks.json` in the parent directory.

When you create your `tasks.json` from the parent directory, it make a `tasks.json` like as your `tasks.json` example.

But if you copy the `tasks.json` created in the subfolder It should be some like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/<change to your subfolder>/<your project>.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

So there is the `.csproj` file, it say in the error.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the FileNotFoundException pointed by mrtedweb, the program not finding the `appsettings.json` can be solved without changing the program code.

Just edit `launch.json`, modifying the `cwd` configuration to point to the project subfolder instead of the root workspace which is the default, from
`cwd: ${workspaceRoot}` to, `${workspaceRoot}/TheProject`.

```
// C:\Solution\.vscode\launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
           {
                "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "launch",
                "preLaunchTask": "build",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/TheProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/TheProject.dll",
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/TheProject",
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "console": "internalConsole",
                "env": {
                    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5050"                
                }            
            }
    ]
}
```

With this launch.json, it's possible to run the application from VS Code opening it from a root solution folder with the project inside a subfolder.

```
C:\Solution>code .
```

And it can also be run from the commandline without changing the paths in the program from the project subfolder.

```
C:\Solution\TheProject>dotnet run TheProject.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

It can no longer locate the appsettings.json file since the project was moved to a subfolder.  This can be easily fixed in the StartUp.cs file by adding the following variable to the constructor:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "<project folder name>", "appsettings.json");
```

*Note: You will need to specify the value for `<project folder name>`.*

Then update the line that reads

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
```

to read:

```
.AddJsonFile(filePath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
```

Also, verify the launch.json file is targeting the proper program file.

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/<project name>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/<program name>.dll"
```

*Note: You will need to specify the values for `<project name>`, and `<program name>`.*