# Visual Studio Code: Could not find the preLaunchTask 'build'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core, vscode-tasks

I have created a new .NET Core application with the command:

```
dotnet new console -o test
```

When I try to run it in the Visual Studio Code debugger, I get:

```
Could not find the preLaunchTask 'build'?
```

Visual Studio Code generated these files for me:

```
tasks.json:
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975641/could-not-find-the-prelaunch-task-build), but in my case there are no mismatches between the names in launch.json and tasks.json for the preLaunchTask so the answer does not apply in this case. I'm running Visual Studio Code version 1.11.2 and .NET Core 1.1 (latest versions as of when this post was created).

I have tried the same on both a Windows machine and a Mac with the same problem. If I do the command "dotnet restore" and "dotnet run", the code runs with no problems, but I still get the same error: "Could not find the preLaunchTask 'build'"

Comment: any solutions @OlavT

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22250

Comment: I think Prelaunch task only works with the version set to 2.0.0 in tasks.json. have a look at the sample provided by jagadeesh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For me, it works to restart VS Code after `tasks.json` and/or `launch.json` files creation.

Also note, that you need to update `"program"` settings in `launch.json` with the path to dlls.

Comment: Thanks restarting VS Code got me past the problem. But, now it complains about problems like: "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported..." Shouldn't VS Code also prompt for a "dotnet restore" to be performed from VS Code? I think I have seen that before.

Comment: In general, it should. Not sure how right now VS code decides when to show that prompt. Anyway, you always may manually do `dotnet restore` from the terminal inside VS Code.

Comment: I also can't recall that I had to manually set the path to the program to debug in the launch.json file. Why can't VS Code do the tricks behind the scene? It should know where to find the executable without involving the user?

Comment: @OlavT this is the [omnisharp-vscode](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) responsibility and the team is going to provide such feature in future. You may look into this [issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1167) if interesting

Answer (score 8):

Change tasks.json as below.

```
tasks.json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "",
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another reason for this error could be, that the used launch configuration is defined inside my_project.code-workspace file (not in launch.json file).
In such case the tasks.json is not used, but tasks must be defined inside the my_project.code-workspace file.

This might be a "feature", but it behaves as a bug, because:

- [tasks doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) says: *Workspace or folder specific tasks are configured from the tasks.json file in the .vscode folder for a workspace.*
- The error "Could not find task 'xxx'." dialog window offers button: `Configure Task` which then opens or offer to create file ./.vscode/tasks.json
- There is no mention or visible hint while editing tasks.json file, that it will not be used.
  This in comparison with e.g. editing setting.json, where in such case text is dimmed and on hover a message says: "This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly."

If a debugging session is started using debug config: my_debug_config (workspace), only tasks defined in my_project.code-workspace file are used.
But while still having the same workspace opened, selecting debug config: dir_debug_config (my_dir), which is defined in the launch.json file, will then use tasks from the tasks.json file.

Comment: exactly my issue.. is there a bug report ?

Comment: I did not find one, nor created a new one. [git](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) has 5k open issues and being misused as a support forum. It seemed pointless to report there.

Comment: posted another answer on a similar open question with links to some relevant bug reports https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967477/

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the paths in `tasks.json` and `launch.json` with absolute paths.

For example in `launch.json`:

```
"program": "C:/Projects/MyProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/XXXX.dll",
"cwd": "C:/Projects/MyProject/"
```

in `tasks.json`:

```
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "build",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "args": [        
      "build",
      "C:/Projects/MyProject/XXXXXX.csproj"
```

Answer (score 0):

This got addressed in master already and will be available in the next release. Reopening VS Code on the folder should help workaround the problem.

Comment: I have the latest version and still have the same problem.  Do I have to manually create a 'tasks.json' file?  One doesn't seem to be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of caution-

If `workspaceFolder` is not at the same level as e.g. the app folder `tasks.json` will not be created and you'll get all of the above errors. I created a subfolder after opening the project and got all the above errors - all fixed after running debug from the correct folder - This could explain the effect of relaunching VS code.