# How/Where is the VS Code task named "tsc: build - tsconfig.json" defined?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm new to VS Code debugging setup so I'm hoping for someone who will provide me with a deeper understanding of how it works. Please note that I have read the documentation, but `preLaunchTask` property in `launch.json` in particular is not clear to me.

Using [VS Code's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging#_javascript-source-map-support), I've created a `launch.json` file and customized the parameters to match my project. This all works.

However, what I'm not understanding is why the value for `preLaunchTask` is `tsc: build - tsconfig.json`. Why does this value work? I can't find any information regarding this other than the example shown in the docs.

Looking through StackOverflow, I see [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975641/could-not-find-the-prelaunch-task-build) on how to customize `preLaunchTask`. It points to the creation of a `tasks.json` file that will execute the command to kick off transpiling the TypeScript code into JavaScript.

Looking at my own project, when I use `tsc: build - tsconfig.json`, it works without having a `task.json` defined under `.vscode` folder. When I change it to anything else, it doesn't work. Does anyone know why that is?

Can anyone point me to the documentation page, perhaps, that explains how this part of `preLaunchTask` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a special globally-defined(?) task provided by the builtin TypeScript Language Support extension. As proof of this, if you disable that extension (you can to find it in the Extensions View if you search `@builtin typescript and javascript`), then that task will no longer be available for selection under the menu that appears if you run `Tasks: Run Task` in the command palette (you may need to click "Show All Tasks..." and search under that state). See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/task/taskProvider.ts. Of initial interest is `getBuildTask`:

```json
private getBuildTask(workspaceFolder: vscode.WorkspaceFolder | undefined, label: string, command: string, args: string[], buildTaskidentifier: TypeScriptTaskDefinition): vscode.Task {
    const buildTask = new vscode.Task(
        buildTaskidentifier,
        workspaceFolder || vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
        vscode.l10n.t("build - {0}", label),
        'tsc',
        new vscode.ShellExecution(command, args),
        '$tsc');
    buildTask.group = vscode.TaskGroup.Build;
    buildTask.isBackground = false;
    return buildTask;
}
```

, which is called in `getTasksForProject`, which is called in `provideTasks` in a loop over all tsconfigs.

You can find examples of people having issues with this task not being defined if you google "`github vscode issues "tsc: build - tsconfig.json"`", but unfortunately many of those tickets don't contain enough info from the issue raiser to figure out the cause. There is, however, this ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87525, where it was found that localization from language packs could interfere with usage of the string "tsc: build - tsconfig", and a localized version of the string needed to be used (not too surprising, given the part of the above code that calls `vscode.l10n.t`).